# Openshift - Impala Connection issue

Tags: python-3.x, database, openshift, database-connection, impala

I have written Python App to connect to Impala cluster using Impyla libraries and it was able to extract the data locally. When I deploy the same code in OCP I get the error as:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/getpass.py", line 169, in getuser
   return pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())[0]
Keyerror: "getpwuid(): uid not found : 1001100000"
```

I have not set the above UID anywhere. UID set in my docker file is 1000.

My python script:

```
from impala.dbapi import connect as iconnect

class ImpalaConnector(object):

   def __init__(self):
      self.engine = create_engine("impala://", creator=self.conn, echo = True)

   def conn(self):
      return iconnect(user='my_uid', password='my_pswd', host='my_host', database='my_db', port=20000, auth_mechanism='LDAP', use_ssl=True)

   def connect(self):
      return self.engine.connect().execution_options(cursor_configuration={'REQUEST_POOL': 'abc'})

impala_connector = ImpalaConnector()
connection = impala_connector.connect()
query = test("select * from tableA limit 5")
result = connection.execute(query)
```

From the error log, excepetion is thrown from the line - result = connection.execute(query). I tried to set the UID as env variable using below line:

```
os.environ['UID'] = 'my_uid'
```

And printed all container env variables in Jenkins file :

```
stages {
    stage('Print Environment Variables') {
        steps {
            script {
                // Use sh step to execute shell command to print environment variables
                sh 'env'
            }
        }
    }
```

But it neither printed UID which I set in my python script or any UID which has value of 1001100000.

Could anyone please provide any input/solutions for this issue ?